# How to set textbox in VB.NET exe from VB.Net dll

Tags: vb.net

I would like to set the text in a textbox in a VB.Net exe from a VB.Net dll.

This may seem strange but the dll gets called inline from another program.

My exe will always be running prior to dll being run and is called "BA_SyncNet.exe", the main class is just "Form1", the Window title is "BA Sync" and the textbox is called "DummyText"

I have tried API calls to FindWindow, FindWindowEx and SendMessage from my "BA_SyncNetChat.dll" without much success. Maybe there are better ways than this as well.

If someone could help I would most appreciate it!
Kind regards

Comment: Why don't you just pass the text box as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this was a bad way to go for my particular solution, as the API's bypassed the .Net events. Which needed to be triggered.

If I didn't need events it would have been a solution... maybe not the best.